# Запуск программы

Tags: кластер, java

Хочу запустить параллельное выполнение программы на кластере. 
Запускаю jar-ник, но тут возникла проблема: на вход программе подается некоторый входной файл. Внутри jar он лежит(экспортировал класс и все ресурсы).
При запуске программы(без передачи этого файла) вылетает ошибка, мол не может найти такого файла.   
Как сделать так, чтобы не передавать входные данные программе, если они в jar лежат?

Пример кода:

```
public class Test3 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] string = line.split("\t");
            .....
            .....
```

}

Comment: Как я понимаю, метод main принимает аргумент "путь к файлу"? Или что подразумевается под фразой "на вход программе подается некоторый входной файл"?

Comment: @Rams666, прикрепил пример кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
java.io.InputStream resStream = Test3.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/text.txt");
if (resStream == null)
    throw SomethingAppropriate();

java.util.Scanner scanner = new Scanner(resStream);
```

Comment: Хм. (1) А вы уверены, что ресурс есть в файле? Перепроверьте. (2) А если вы заходите в jar архиватором, в каком подкаталоге ресурс? (3) вы не забыли же исправить в исходнике имя файла, да?

Comment: [Документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) сообщает:

> Returns:
>    A InputStream object or `null` if no resource with this name is found

Что-то не так с именем у вас.

Comment: Переложил файл в папку src и все заработало.    
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну слава богу, а то уже какая-то мистика получалась.  
Пожалуйста!

Comment: Можно еще спросить - можно ли сделать так, чтобы, скажем вот в папке проекта, в которой лежат lib, src, bin лежал тот самый test.txt?

Comment: @Stas0n: думаю, [вот это](http://technotes.tostaky.biz/2012/08/understanding-absolute-and-relative.html) должно помочь разобраться. Важно не где лежит файл в исходниках, а где он появится в `.jar`.

Comment: просто создавая jar из проекта, в корне которого лежал то самый test.txt, resStream был налом. Правильно ли я понимаю, что всегда входные файлы стоит класть внутрь папки src?

Comment: @Stas0n: Не знаю, как именно ваше IDE производит jar, поэтому "просто создавая jar из проекта" может значить очень разное. Лучше почитать документацию, ну или поэкспериментировать (с риском нарваться на сюрприз).

Comment: У меня eclipse.
Хорошо, будем пробовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В случае с файлом, лежащим в jar его нужно доставать, как resource.

Вот пример кода:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

String name = "test.txt";
InputStream stream = Test3.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
File file = File.createTempFile(name, ".tmp");
file.deleteOnExit();
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, file);
```

Comment: а scanner на вход что давать? Что за переменная name? и еще..
> FileUtils cannot be resolved

Comment: 1. На вход scanner подаете file
2. Переменная name - это имя временного файла (может быть любое, все равно файл удаляется при завершении программы)
2. FileUtils - метод из apacheвской библиотеки "commons-io"

Comment: > NullPointerException в FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, file);
     
Точнее stream==null